# Key Filters fields which contain Managed metadata columns will float out of the layout if i move the mouse over one of the managed metadata fields

Tags: javascript, development, jquery, css, page-layout

I am working on an enterprise wiki site collection inside sharepoint farm 2013 on-premises. now i enable the metadata navigation and filtering site feature, and i added 5 managed metadata site columns. then i wrote the following script/css to move the key filters fields to be displayed on the top of the page instead of being shown on the left hand side of the screen:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document ).ready(function() {
 $("#idKeyFiltersContainer").appendTo("#DeltaPageStatusBar");
$ ("#idKeyFiltersHeader").insertAfter("#idKeyFiltersContainer");
$ ("<p></p>").insertBefore("#idKeyFiltersHeader");
$ ("<hr/>").insertAfter("#idKeyFiltersHeader");
$ ("<hr/>").insertBefore("#idKeyFiltersContainer");
});
</script>
<Style type="text/css">
.ms-KFHeadV3.ms-KFHead
{
display:none;
}
#navresizerHorizontalBar
{
display:none;
}
#ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_PlaceHolderQuickLaunchBottom_idNavLinkViewAll
{
display:none;
}
.ms-tv.box {
display:none; /* Hide the Key filters until the jquery has moved the element */
margin-left:0px; /* Align the key element Div with "New Item buttons" */
    }
#idKeyFiltersContainer {
        width: auto !important; /* Stretch the background color for the key filter buttons */
    }
 .ms-KFLabelAndBodyContainer {
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
width:fixed !important;
height:fixed !important;
    }
    #navresizerVerticalBarPositionHelper {
        display: none; /* Hides the vertical bar that allows stretching the left navigation */
    }
.ms-standardheader.ms-KFLabel
{
color:#008cd2;
font-weight:bold;
}
hr{ height: 12px; border: 0; box-shadow: inset 0 12px 12px -12px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }

</style>
```

now the key filters got moved correctly to the top of the page, as follow:-

[image]

but the problem will occur when i moved the mouse focus over the "standard" key filter, where the key filters will float wrongly as follow:-
[image]

now on other projects i use the same script/css to move the key filters and it is working well. but on those projects the key filters are drop-down lists and not managed metadata columns. so is there a way to fix this? so the key filters will not float when i move the mouse over them?